# How to select a specific value from a list in python

Tags: python

So I have the following MCMC sampler  -

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math

def targ_dist2(x1,x2):

    target2 = (mlab.bivariate_normal(x1, x2, 1.0, 1.0, -6, -6, 0.9) + 
mlab.bivariate_normal(x1, x2, 1.0, 1.0, 4, 4, -0.9) + 
mlab.bivariate_normal(x1, x2, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0))/3
    return target2

nSamples = 5000
propSigma = 2      
x = np.zeros((nSamples+1,2))
xCurrent = stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-5, scale=10, size=2, random_state=None)
dims = range(2)

#INITIAL VALUES
t = 0
x[t,0] = xCurrent[0]
x[t,1] = xCurrent[1]

while t < nSamples:
    t = t + 1
    for iD in range(2):
        xStar = np.random.normal(x[t-1,iD], propSigma)
        alpha = min(1, (targ_dist2(xStar, x[t-1,iD!=dims]) / targ_dist2(x[t-
        1,iD], x[t-1,iD!=dims])))

        #ACCEPT OR REJECT
        u = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if u < alpha:
            x[t,iD] = xStar
        else:
            x[t,iD] = x[t-1,iD]
```

My error is where I have the != in the alpha equation. Basically here I would like to choose the value in "dims" that is not equal to the value "iD" in the loop. So, for example, if the loop is working through the value iD=0, I would like to have the value 1 in place of iD!=dims in the alpha equation above (if that makes sense). Is there a general way of doing this? I hope to extend this algorithm to multiple dimensions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have doesn't really make sense because you are comparing a range with a value. iD is an `int` but dims is a `range` so comparing them doesn't really make sense.

maybe something like this would be better

```
def get_opposite(iD, dims):
    for x in dims:
        if x != iD: #Beware here for multi dimentional extension
            return x
```

Then change your offending line to:

```
... x[t-1,get_opposite(iD,dims)]...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to work! Would you by any chance know how to extend this in the multivariate case? Say if we were working in 10 dimensions for example?

Comment: well what would returned in the 10 d case? Currently we have `(x,y)` and we return the value for the one not given. If we had `(x,y,z,k....)` then given `x` what should it return?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you want, but if it's to just print the opposite value of iD, if it is a `range(2)`, thus 1 and 0:

```
for i in range(2):
  print("i value: ", i)
  print("opposite:" ,1- i)
```